# Ruby Object ID method not working

Tags: ruby

I am following through www.ruby-doc's tutorial on Classes and Objects, which has the code:

```
person = "Tim"
person.id   »   537771100
person.type »   String
person      »   "Tim"
```

I tried the code below:

```
person = "Tim"
person.id
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for "Tim":String
```

Why does it return the error after I call `id` on my new variable?

Answer (score 4):

In recent rubies the methods are `object_id` and `class`:

```
person = "Tim"
person.object_id # => 66765660 (varies)
person.class     # => String
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that the official docs site is hosting such an outdated version of the Pickaxe. I wonder if Pragmatic Programmers could be persuaded to license a more recent edition.

Comment: i encountered the exact problem going thru the exact ruby-doc tutorial - this helped solve it